# extract String between last slash and question mark

Tags: android

I want to extract string between last slash and question mark using **regex**

```
String path="http://keting.amazonaws.com/media123/mediaattachments/000/000/004/original/Shoes_TVC_2013.mp4?1470248308"
```

I need to get "Shoes_TVC_2013.mp4" from the String.

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("NEED HELP HERE");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(URL);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); //prints region/country
    } else {
        System.out.println("Match not found");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.*\/(.*)\?` should do the trick. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/xZ9wD1/1) for more.

Comment: You should mark the post that worked for you as the best answer, that way others know what works :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution,

```
String path="http://keting.amazonaws.com/media123/mediaattachments/000/000/004/original/Shoes_TVC_2013.mp4?1470248308";

path = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1,path.lastIndexOf("?"));
```

Comment: Basically I need Regex